# Adjacency List in C for undirected (unweighted) graph

Tags: c, linked-list, graph-algorithm, undirected-graph

Here is my code:

```
#define V 5

typedef struct edge* link;

//structure for reprenting edges
typedef struct edge{
    int dst;        //number of destination node
    //int weight;   //for weigthed graphs
    link next;      //link to next edge
} edge_t;

link new_edge(int dst, link next) {
    link edge = (link) malloc(sizeof(edge_t));

    edge->dst = dst;
    edge->next = next;
    return edge;
}

int main() {

    link edge;
    link adj[V];
    //the array contains V pointers to lists of edges
    //each list for each node of my graph

    int i;
    int j;

    //all lists are empty at beginning
    for (i = 0; i < V; i ++) {
        adj[i] = NULL;
    }

    printf("input the edges:\n");
    
    while (scanf("%d %d", &i, &j) == 2) {
        adj[i] = new_edge(j, adj[i]);
        //in the list for node i
        //put the edge to node j
        adj[j] = new_edge(i, adj[j]); //if it is undirect
        //in the list for node j
        //put the edge to node i
    }
    
    printf("adjacency list is: \n");
    //cycle over the nodes
    for (i=0; i<V; i++) {
        if (adj[i] == NULL) {
            printf("%d is null list\n", i);
        }
        //print all the edges for that node
        for (edge = adj[i]; edge != NULL; edge = edge -> next) {
            printf("edge %d -> %d\n", i, edge->dst);
        }
    }
}
```

INPUT:
0 1

0 2

1 3
stop
OUTPUT:
adjacency list is:
edge 0 -> 2
edge 0 -> 1
edge 1 -> 3
edge 1 -> 0
edge 2 -> 0
edge 3 -> 1
4 is null list

This image shows how my **new_edge** function works, blue area(in pic) is changing so I can traverse through the list, so my question is why blue area is equal to NULL?, cause it is pointing to last item in the list, I thought it won't be NULL(P.S I verified it is null when I traversed through the list in order to print it).

[image]

Comment: Is your question why `adj[4]` is null?

Comment: No, the first one of the list(of pointers aka adj[0]) will be null I'm asking about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of `adj` are pointers to nodes, not nodes.
On the other hand, what `next` in the nodes point at are nodes, not pointers to nodes.
Therefore, `next` will not point at the elements of `adj`.

This is how your code actually work:

[image: how your code actually work]

As you see, the pointers are not looping back and your blue area (elements of `adj` that have nodes added) is not equal to `NULL`.